# Clicking hyperlink doesnt trigger travel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular app with tabs. I have a navbar with a dropdown that looks like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href="/page1">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page2#/tab1/">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page2#/tab2">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I'm on page 1, I can travel to either page 2 or page 3 just fine. The url changes and the page loads to show the content on that tab.

The problem is this: When I'm on page 2 or page 3, clicking the hyperlink to the other page causes the url to change BUT the page does NOT load new content.

How do I ensure that the behaviour of the hyperlink is consistent no matter which page I'm on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Page 2' and 'Page 3' are the same page (page2). Anything after the # in the URL is the fragment identifier, and the fragment identifier indicates where on the page you should be sent to when loaded.

Generally when you're using variables like 'tab1', you'd have JavaScript load that tab (which is beyond the scope of this question)

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Examples
(Bonus: Notice how your browser takes you straight to the 'Examples' section?)

Update: In the comments, you mention wanting to make the page changes seem consistent... The following code should work as it adds a 'query' parameter to the URL - so while it still points to the same file, the browser needs to refresh the URL as it can't be sure the same content will be provided from the webserver.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href="/page1">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page2?tab=1#/tab1/">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page2?tab=2#/tab2">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Clever bonus.

But what I want is a hyperlink that behaves consistently, no matter what page you're on. In your example, when I click the link it opens wikipedia in a new tab. Scrolling up and clicking on proposals though simply jumps the page down to proposals.

What I want is for both hyperlinks to open the link in a new tab (or whatever else the user has set up, so that the hyperlink is consistent)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a code sample that will do what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href="#page1">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="page1">Content of Page 1</div>
<div id="page2">Content of Page 2</div>
<div id="page3">Content of Page 3</div>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
<script type="text/javscript">
    $('#page1').click(function() {
        $('#page1').show();
        $('#page2').hide();
        $('#page3').hide();
    })
    $('#page2').click(function() {
        $('#page2').show();
        $('#page1').hide();
        $('#page3').hide();
    })
    $('#page3').click(function() {
        $('#page3').show();
        $('#page2').hide();
        $('#page3').hide();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This has the downside of putting the scope of all of my pages onto a single page. It doesn't mesh well with angular (programmatcially switching controllers?) and most importantly doesn't persist through a page refresh.

Comment: What do you mean @ForrestKeppler ? I think it could work properly. When you click on Page 1, your link will be like this: {yourlink}#page1  And then it would be scroll to your Content Of Page 1. Using Hide() for hiding content which is not essential to display. If you think you gonna use a flexible content, just play with your Ajax. :)